# Configure asp.net core swagger to mark non-nullable types as required

Tags: swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

Can Swagger/Swashbuckle be configured to behave by default as if `[Required]` attribute is added to every property whose type is not explicitly nullable.

E.g. if I have a response:

```
public class FooResponse {
    [Required]
    public string Bar {get;set;}
}
```

I want to avoid having to put `[Required]` since the property type is `string` rather than `string?`.

How do I configure Swagger schema generator to do that?

*UPDATE*
Here is what I came up with so far, a bit simplistic but addresses most of the structures I'm using:

```
/**
 * Mark properties that are non-nullable as required.
 */
public class NullableSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter {
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context) {
        if (schema.Type == "object") {
            foreach (var openApiSchema in schema.Properties) {
                if (openApiSchema.Value.Nullable == false) {
                    schema.Required.Add(openApiSchema.Key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What library do you use - Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, Swagger-Net, NSwag, something else?

Comment: @Helen, my bad. I have updated the question. I'm using Swashbuckle.